# Pandas Compare Similar DataFrames and get Min

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, min

Given the following data frames:

```
d1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,np.nan],'B':[np.nan,5,6]})
d1.index=['A','B','E']

    A       B
A   1.0     NaN
B   2.0     5.0
E   NaN     6.0

d2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,2,np.nan,4],'B':[4,2,np.nan,4]})
d2.index=['A','B','C','D']
    A       B
A   4.0     4.0
B   2.0     2.0
C   NaN     NaN
D   4.0     4.0
```

I'd like to compare them to find the lowest value in each corresponding row, while preserving all rows indices from both.
Here is the result I'm looking for:

```
    A       B
A   1.0     4.0
B   2.0     2.0
C   NaN     NaN
D   4.0     4.0
E   NaN     6.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option by `aligning` the two data frames (both index and columns) firstly, then use `numpy.fmin`:

```
pd.np.fmin(*d1.align(d2))
```

[image]

Less convoluted:

```
d1, d2 = d1.align(d2)
pd.np.fmin(d1, d2)
```

Comment: I love this!  But you know you just put another tool in my toolbox :-)

Answer (score 8):

You can concat the dfs and then use groupby to keep the min

```
df = pd.concat([d1,d2])
df = df.groupby(df.index).min()
```

You get

```
    A   B
A   1.0 4.0
B   2.0 2.0
C   NaN NaN
D   4.0 4.0
E   NaN 6.0
```

EDIT: More concise solutions from @root and @ScottBoston

```
pd.concat([d1, d2]).groupby(level=0).min()
```

Comment: or df = df.groupby(df.index).min()

Comment: or in a single line `pd.concat([d1, d2]).groupby(level=0).min()`

Answer (score 4):

Use `pd.Panel` with `min`
Also note that this is generalizable to any number of dataframes.

```
pd.Panel(dict(enumerate([d1, d2]))).min(0)

     A    B
A  1.0  4.0
B  2.0  2.0
C  NaN  NaN
D  4.0  4.0
E  NaN  6.0
```